# Pygame: Mouse Specific Axis Detection

Tags: python, pygame, mouse

How can I detect ONLY the X axis, for example?

```
maus_x = 0
maus_y = 0
pygame.mouse.get_pos(maus_x, maus_y)

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:         
        if maus_x < wx_coord:
            angle += 10
```

In theory, this "pygame.mouse.get_pos" returns a tuple (x, y). But, I'm defining there a variable to represent the x and y in this tuple. The thing is, when I move the mouse (pygame.MOUSEMOTION), when I do what is written in "maus_x < wx_coord:", it executes the function with the Y axis too. And that makes no sense at all.

"angle +=10" must be executed ONLY when I move the mouse in the x axis. Anyone have any idea of what is happening? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how function calls work. In your code, `maus_x` is always `0`, since nothing ever modifies it. You want:

```
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:      
            mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()   
            if mousex < wx_coord:
                angle += 10
```

In fact, you probably just want to inspect the [event](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) object directly:

```
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:      
            mousex, mousey = event.pos   
            if mousex < wx_coord:
                angle += 10
```

Or better yet:

```
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:      
            relx, rely = event.rel   
            if relx != 0:  # x movement
                angle += 10
```

Comment: I've tried that already, it does not work.

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            maus_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if maus_x > 0:
                angle += 10

It executes the "angle += 10" in the y axis too, as if the "get_pos" function returns only one value (mouse movement, no matter in what axis)

Comment: @EricsonWillians You don't want `if maus_x > 0:`, you want what is in the third example

Comment: `maus_x > 0` is almost always going to be true, since the coordinates of the mouse should never be negative

Comment: Thank you very much! I've understood now! :) I've tested your third example, it did exactly what I wanted, thank you.