# Position of curosr when print out is always fixed at (0,0) - Pygame (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, pygame

I'm following a tutorial online, trying to get the position of the cursor,
however, when I print the cursor, the location/position of the cursor is always fixed at (0,0). What had happen? How could I fix it?

```
def gameIntro():

            cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            print cur

            pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,(240,200,120,50))
            textToButton("Start",black,240,200,120,50)
            pygame.display.update()
            while True:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()

                clock.tick(20)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     gameIntro()
     exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` gets called only once. Add it to your main game loop like:

```
...
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    print cur
...
```

For more info have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285889/pygame-mouse-get-pos-not-working) question.

Comment: Im actually trying to run this code as well
                if 240 +120 > cur[0] > 240 and 200 + 50 > cur[1] > 200:
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen,yellow,(240,200,120,50))
                else:
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,(240,200,120,50))

where when I hover over it, it will change color..

Comment: As far as I understood your question was why mouse.get_pos() doesn't get updated. If you have more problems with your code open a new question please ^^

Answer (score 0):

just try

```
print(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
```

What version of pygame are you using? what version of python ar eyou using? it seems you have got 2.7 up and running, are you sure you have the matching pygame version with that?

Comment: no he doesnt. there are differences because of the differences between python 3 and 2.7

Comment: Python 2.7 and i've downloaded the correct version for pygame(the latest).

Comment: He did not specify whether he downloaded the correct version for pygame in correlation to 2.7. he only specified the python version.

Comment: ygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",25)


is this type in your code as well?

Comment: should be pygame.font , accidentally delete the p

Comment: no the line above looks like its cut off early... remove the 2 enters..
does the rest of your code work well?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "reduced" version of the program, to reproduce the problem.

```
import pygame
def gameIntro():
  cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
  print cur
if __name__ == "__main__":
  pygame.init()
  gameIntro()
```

I also get `(0,0)`.

In the pygame documentation, http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html, it says that all these mouse informations are updated by the event queue.  The call to `mouse.get_pos()`is made when entering `gameIntro()`, that's probably why the position has not been updated yet.

Maybe try to call it again in your main loop.