# Crash when running a program that uses boundary checks (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

When I run my code the window automatically crashes. I can't seem to find any reason as to why. This is a very simple piece of code so context isn't required :)

Here's the code:

```
import pygame
size=(0,0)
WHITE=(255,255,255)
BLACK=(0,0,0)
rectX=(0)
rectY=(0)
rectSizeX=(100)
rectSizeY=(100)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
screen.fill(WHITE)
pygame.display.flip()
while (True):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, [rectX, rectY, rectSizeX, rectSizeY])
    pygame.display.flip()
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    while mouse_pos[0] >= (rectX) and mouse_pos[1] >= (rectY) and mouse_pos[0] <= (rectX+rectSizeX) and mouse_pos[1] <= (rectY+rectSizeY):
        print("meme")
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

Comment: Please and also for future questions, post the error you get not just your code.

Comment: No error comes up in the python shell. The pygame screen just stops responding

Comment: Seems like you dont handle the mouse events correctly. Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285889/pygame-mouse-get-pos-not-working#16286076

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pygame mouse.get\_pos() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285889/pygame-mouse-get-pos-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version for now:

```
import pygame
import sys
size=(0,0)
WHITE=(255,255,255)
BLACK=(0,0,0)
rectX=(0)
rectY=(0)
rectSizeX=(100)
rectSizeY=(100)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
screen.fill(WHITE)

pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, [rectX, rectY, rectSizeX, rectSizeY])
pygame.display.flip()
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if mouse_pos[0] >= (rectX) and mouse_pos[1] >= (rectY) and mouse_pos[0] <= (rectX+rectSizeX) and mouse_pos[1] <= (rectY+rectSizeY):
                print("meme")
            else:
                print (mouse_pos)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Also note your window is not "not responding" but you cant close it because you need to handle the `QUIT` type event too.